# Nighwatch with Standalone Chrome

Tags: javascript, selenium, nightwatch.js

Im trying to use nightwatch with standalone selenium (without manually starting selenium through nightwatch). I want it to run without opening the browser. Here is my configuration

```
  output_folder: 'test/reports',
  custom_assertions_path: '',
  page_objects_path: "test/page-objects",

  selenium: {
    start_process: false,
  },

  test_settings: {
    default: {
      launch_url : 'http://localhost/dist',
      selenium_port: 4446,
      selenium_host: "xxx.xxx.xx.xx",
      desiredCapabilities: {
        browserName: 'chrome',
        chromeOptions : {
          args : ["--no-sandbox"]
        },
      },
    }
  },
```

But this is not locating the elements and the test fails. However, if I change the configuration to start the selenium server and run with chrome as in the following configuration, it works perfectly.

```
selenium: {
start_process: true,
server_path: seleniumServerPath,
cli_args: {  
  'webdriver.chrome.driver': chromedriverPath,
 },
},

test_settings: {
  default: {
    launch_url : 'http://localhost/dist',
    desiredCapabilities: {
      browserName: 'chrome',
    },
  }
},
```

What am I missing? I want it to run inside gitlab runner.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. It worked with the following config

```
"selenium": {
    "start_process": false,
    "server_path": seleniumServerPath,
    "cli_args": {  
      'webdriver.chrome.driver': chromedriverPath,
    },
  },

  "test_settings" : {
    "default" : {
      "launch_url" : 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:8000',
      "selenium_port"  : 4446,
      "selenium_host"  : "xxx.xxx.xxx.xx",
      "silent": true,
      "screenshots" : {
        "enabled" : true,
        "on_failure" : true,
        "on_error" : false,
        "path" : "tmp/screenshots"
      },
      "desiredCapabilities": {
        "browserName": "chrome",
        "chromeOptions" : {
          "args" : ["--no-sandbox"]
        },
        "acceptSslCerts": true
      }
    },
  },
```